# Show tooltip for only one layer in ggplot2 and plotly

Tags: r, ggplot2, plotly

Is it possible to show tooltips for only one layer in ggplot + plotly, even if multiple layers share one aestetic. In this example I would like to show only the blue tooltip at the blue line from the `geom_smooth` layer but don't show the black tooltip for each point.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(plotly)
library(palmerpenguins)

gg <- ggplot(penguins, aes(x=flipper_length_mm, y=body_mass_g)) + 
  geom_point() + 
  geom_smooth(se = FALSE)

ggplotly(gg, tooltip=c("y")) %>%
  layout(hovermode = "x unified")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can suppress the tooltip on black dots using the `style` function:

```
ggplotly(gg, tooltip=c("y")) %>%
  layout(hovermode = "x unified") %>%
  style(hoverinfo = "skip", traces = 1)
```

For more examples, see chapter [Controlling Tooltips](https://plotly-r.com/controlling-tooltips.html) of the book *Interactive web-based data visualization with R, plotly, and shiny*.